# Adobe Acrobat Form - Text Field Issue

Tags: forms, pdf, adobe, acrobat, fillable

I have created a fillable form.  The form works correctly and can be filled in easily when I open it in Adobe Acrobat Pro or Adobe Acrobat Reader DC on my **Desktop**.

However, when I open the same form on a **smartphone (android)**, the text field does not work as expected.  A single letter does not go into each separate box. (I am using Adobe Acrobat Reader app)

Is there any way to ensure a single letter will go into each separate box?

(BTW, When I right click on the text field and choose Properties, I have Comb of 15 characters set under options.)

[image].

Comment: How did you make your form fill in box-by-box? If you did it incorrectly, we may help you fix it. If you did it correctly, you should file a bug with Adobe.

Comment: Hi mkl.  I made it in MS Word and used a table (1 Row X 16 Columns), for each entry e.g. Name, Country, Contact No. and Message.  This was then saved as a PDF.  I used Comb of ____ characters and this made it fill in box-by-box on the desktop but not on Android 11 phone.  I have also since posted a question with the Adobe community so maybe there might be a solution somewhere, if not, no worries. Thanks, Andy.

Comment: Ok. You might want to post that as an actual *answer*, not merely a *comment*, here.

Answer (score 2):

I have asked on the Adobe Forums and the reply was that PDF Readers on Phones / Tablets are not full-fledged readers and do not support all options.

If anyone on the forum does come across a piece of code in the future that will space the characters (without using 'Comb of Characters'), I would be grateful!